# Full rank of $A+B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be two matrices of order $d \times n, d<n$. If $A$ has rank $d$ and $B$ has rank $k(0 \leq k \leq d)$, then what is the condition to make $A+B$ of rank $d$?

Comment: No it is not. Consider the matrices $A = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$, which is $2 \times 3$ matrix with rank $2$. Now, consider $B = -A$. Then, $A + B = 0$ whose rank is $0$.

Comment: Is there any condition we can make such that it is possible?

Comment: Obviously if rank of $B$ is $0$

Comment: If rank of B=d-1 (say)?

Comment: If $B=cA$ for $c \neq -1$, $A+B$ will have the same rank as $A$. You can even set rows of $cA$ to $0$ and the rank will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, $A+B$ could have a rank of anything, for example take $B = -A$, in this case, $rank(A)=rank(B)=d$, but $rank(A+B)=rank(O)=0$.

Concrete example:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = -A =\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
\ 0 & -1 \ \\
\end{bmatrix} \\ A + B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Even though $rank(A)=rank(B)=2$, $rank(A+B)=rank(O)=0$

Comment: rank of B \leq rank of A

Answer (score 0):

Consider each $d \times d$ submatrix, corresponding to a choice of $d$ columns of $A+B$.
$A+B$ has rank $d$ if and only if at least one of these $d \times d$ submatrices has 
nonzero determinant.